# How start a service (module2) from another activity (in module1) in android studio?

Tags: android

i have a project in android studio with 2 modules: wear and mobile. In the wear module i have a WearService and in the mobile module i have HandActivity. I want to start the WearService from the HandActivity, only pressing the button. How can i do it? Im trying to use that code, but it wasnt working.

```
package com.example.joe.activitytoactivity;

public class WearService extends WearableListenerService {
public WearService() {
}


@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

and

```
package com.example.joe.activitytoactivity;

public class HandActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hand);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_hand, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(HandActivity.this,com.example.joe.activitytoactivity.WearService.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Where is the problem? My android studio say that part is wrong: Intent(HandActivity.this,com.example.joe.activitytoactivity.WearService.class

Edit:In the Intent, the IDE says: cannot resolve symbol "WearService"

OBS: Sorry for may english.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`Intent intent = new Intent(HandActivity.this,com.example.ewelton.activitytoactivity.WearService.class)`

Try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,WearService.class);
```

Also, any new activity needs to be declared in the AndroidManifest like such:

```
<activity
    android:name = "com.example.joe.activitytoactivity.WearService"
    android:label = "optionalname"
</activity>
```

Comment: I already did it, but it didnt work. PS: in Intent(HandActivity.this,com.example.ewelton.activitytoactivity.WearService.class) i already change ewelton to joe.

Comment: What's the error message? And have you declared WearServices in AndroidManifest as an activity?

Comment: In the Intent, the IDE says: cannot resolve symbol "WearService"

Comment: instead of new Intent(this,WearService.class);  try new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WearService.class); since you're passing your intent to another class.

Comment: It didnt work. I need configure anything on Manifest?